# Assistance writing multi-level, many-to-many join while only allowing duplicates from the first level

Tags: sql-server

I am stuck in the middle of trying to write a SQL query that leverages multiple joins for tables that are only related through many-to-many mappings. I cannot alter any of the table structures and I cannot add any more relation rows in the mapping tables, so what they've given me is all I have to work with.

I realize there are several questions in here about duplicate rows in many-to-many queries, but I think this one is slightly different because I want to allow duplicates, but only from the first set of joins.

This is part of a CMDB application, and the relationships do work in real life because the GUI can correctly display the related data. Unfortunately, my SQL knowledge is nowhere near bordering proficient so I’d like to reach out to you all for help.

Here are my tables:

**Circuits:**

```
 ID    Name     CircuitID  
 ---- --------- ----------- 
   1   P2P-CKT       02001
```

**Devices:**

```
 ID    Name     Serial  
 ---- --------- -------- 
   1   NWRTR01   A001    
   2   NWRTR99   A099
```

**Ports:**

```
ID   Name   
 ---- ------- 
   1   GE0/0  
   2   GE2/1
```

**IPs:**

```
 ID      Name      
 ---- ------------- 
   1   192.168.0.1  
   2   192.168.0.2
```

**Relationships:**

```
 ID   Source_ID   Source_Type   Dest_ID   Dest_Type  
 ---- ----------- ------------- --------- ----------- 
   1           1   Circuit             1   Device     
   2           1   Circuit             2   Device     
   3           1   Circuit             1   Port       
   4           1   Circuit             2   Port       
   5           1   Device              1   Port       
   6           2   Device              2   Port       
   7           1   Port                1   IP         
   8           2   Port                2   IP
```

Here is what I need the results to look like:

```
 Circuit ID   Device Name   Device Serial   Port Name     Port IP    
 ------------ ------------- --------------- ----------- ------------- 
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR01       A001            GE0/0       192.168.0.1  
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR99       A099            GE2/1       192.168.0.2
```

I'm allowing the Circuit ID to be duplicated once for each device it's connected to but that's where I want the duplication to stop. However, because of the way my mappings table is defined, all I can seem to build is:

```
Circuit ID   Device Name   Device Serial   Port Name     Port IP    
 ------------ ------------- --------------- ----------- ------------- 
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR01       A001            GE0/0       192.168.0.1  
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR01       A001            GE2/1       192.168.0.2  
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR99       A099            GE0/0       192.168.0.1  
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR99       A099            GE2/1       192.168.0.2
```

I start by taking a traditional join approach such that my query is:

```sql
    SELECT
        Circuits.Name as 'Circuit ID',
        Devices.Name as 'Device Name',
        Devices.Serial as 'Device Serial'
    FROM
        Circuits
    
    --Establish the many-to-many mappings for the DEVICES
    LEFT JOIN
        Relationships rel_devices (NOLOCK) on Circuits.ID = rel_devices.Source_ID
        AND rel_devices.Source_Type = 'Circuit'
        AND rel_devices.Dest_Type = 'Device'
    
    --Join the devices
    LEFT JOIN
        Devices on rel_devices.Dest_ID  = Devices.ID
```

And so far, I get the results I'm looking for:

```
 Circuit ID   Device Name   Device Serial  
 ------------ ------------- --------------- 
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR01       A001           
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR99       A099
```

However, as soon as I start to join the ports, things begin to run off the rails. Following the same logic above, I want to build the many-to-many mappings for the ports and join them to the circuits. But this ends up duplicating my existing rows.

```sql
SELECT
    Circuits.Name as 'Circuit ID',
    Devices.Name as 'Device Name',
    Devices.Serial as 'Device Serial',
    Ports.Name as 'Port Name'
FROM
    Circuits

--Establish the many-to-many mappings for the DEVICES
LEFT JOIN
    Relationships rel_devices (NOLOCK) on Circuits.ID = rel_devices.Source_ID
    AND rel_devices.Source_Type = 'Circuit'
    AND rel_devices.Dest_Type = 'Device'

--Join the devices
LEFT JOIN
    Devices on rel_devices.Dest_ID  = Devices.ID


--Establish the many-to-many mappings for the PORTS
LEFT JOIN
    Relationships rel_ports (NOLOCK) on Circuits.ID = rel_ports.Source_ID
    AND rel_ports.Source_Type = 'Circuit'
    AND rel_ports.Dest_Type = 'Port'

--Join the ports
LEFT JOIN
    Ports on rel_ports.Dest_ID = Ports.ID
```

```
 Circuit ID   Device Name   Device Serial   Port Name  
 ------------ ------------- --------------- ----------- 
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR01       A001            GE0/0      
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR01       A001            GE2/1      
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR99       A099            GE0/0      
  P2P-CKT      NWRTR99       A099            GE2/1
```

I do understand why it’s duplicating the data: because the two ports are related to the circuit just like the two devices are. I know it's not the query's fault, it's doing exactly what it's *supposed* to, but I'm afraid I don't know how to write it so it does what I *want* it to do.

I’m thinking that leveraging grouping with the joins is the way to go but when I tried testing it, I started discovering that there’s special criteria that have to be met with your selected columns when you use grouping with a `having` clause. I could be chasing a red-herring though.

I think the IPs will be easier to map because my mappings table does contain port to IP mappings, I just can't figure out how to map the ports to the devices such that it isn't duplicating the rows.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How would you know to only return `GE0/0` for `NWRTR01` and `GE2/1` for `NWRTR99`, when your relationships have `GE0/0` and `GE2/1` for both Devices? Why not remove the relationships if you don't want those relationships associated with results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by adding an extra clause to your join to `Relationships` to for ports. This ensures you only bring back ports that are related to both the circuit and the device:

```
--Establish the many-to-many mappings for the PORTS
LEFT JOIN dbo.Relationships AS rel_ports
    ON  Circuits.ID = rel_ports.Source_ID
    AND rel_ports.Source_Type = 'Circuit'
    AND rel_ports.Dest_Type = 'Port'
    AND EXISTS 
    (   SELECT 1  
        FROM    dbo.Relationships AS pd 
        WHERE   pd .Source_Type = 'Device' 
        AND     pd.Dest_Type = 'Port' 
        AND     pd.Source_ID = Devices.ID
        AND     pd.Dest_ID = rel_ports.Dest_ID
    )
```

Which gives:

```
Circuit ID  Device Name     Device Serial   Port NAME
-----------------------------------------------------
P2P-CKT     NWRTR01         A001            GE0/0
P2P-CKT     NWRTR99         A099            GE2/1
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/98982/4)**

As a side note you may want to read this - [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere).

Also, if this is your design, I would change it, and create a separate relationship table for each relationship. This will make your queries less clunky to write, and mean that you can use referential integrity properly. It also means that you are in control of what relationships can be defined. If Circuits don't map to IPs, then you won't need a circuit/IP mapping table, but as it stands there is no way to prevent someone mapping a circuit to an IP in your table.

If you ever need all the data combined, you can always create a view that `UNION`s your different relationship tables together.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much! Also, thank you for the NOLOCK reference! Unfortunately, this isn't my design - it's actually a pre-packaged table from a CMDB application that runs nightly and dumps its data to a SQL warehouse.